# Use Azure Functions with trigger http, input DocumentDB using ID based from http request

Tags: azure, azure-functions

So what I read from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings), is that I should be able to have:

1. trigger HTTP
2. input Http request
3. input DocumentDb
4. output DocumentDb

Numbers 1, 2 and 4 are working. But how to get a document from DocumentDB with the ID from the path?

Can I use the `{path}` from the proxy-route in my DocumentDb Input?

I have a proxy defined like so.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "index": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "{*path}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_SITE_NAME%.azurewebsites.net/api/Index"
        },
        "api": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "api/{*path}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_SITE_NAME%.azurewebsites.net/api/{path}"
        },
        "index existing subscription": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/subscription/{*path}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_SITE_NAME%.azurewebsites.net/api/IndexSubscription/{path}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Function with Document DB input binding.

`function.json`

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "route": "MyDocFunc/{docid}"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "MyDocDB",
      "collectionName": "MyCollection",
      "id": "{docid}",
      "connection": "mydocdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

`csx`

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    HttpRequestMessage req, string docid, string inputDocument)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, inputDocument);
}
```

The usage of proxy doesn't affect this much... You can pass your proxy parameter to function parameter.

Comment: So instead of `{*path}` I should use `{path}` that's all the difference?

Comment: @Highmastdon `*` matches all the remaining path segments. Not sure why you would use it for document ID, but `*` in proxies shouldn't hurt either. Are you getting any specific problems?